# why some nested aggregate case does not work?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, aggregate-functions

such as: `select sum(b),sum(c),sum(sum(b)+sum(c)) from t1 group by a;`

in oracle, it give the exception: 'ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression' pointer to b in sum(b).

in my opinion, the plan is:

first step:

```
select sum(b),sum(c) from t1 group by a; //sub1
```

second step:

```
select sum(sum(b)+sum(c)) from sub1;
```

why oracle give the exception?

Comment: Why not simply use `sum(a + b)`?

Comment: thanks, the pointer is that syntax exception, it's the oracle bug?

Comment: Nope, In my opinion, It is not a bug. what you are expecting by `sum(sum(a)+sum(b))` it is nothing but the sum of all values of `a` and `b` columns, which is represented as `sum(a) + sum(b)` or `sum` is aggregate function but not the addition function.

Comment: No, it's not a bug. Nesting aggregates simply isn't supported

Comment: No, it's not a bug. If you really want to write that, you have to use the analytical version for the 3rd sum : sum(sum(b)+sum(c)) over () , or you do it in a using a sub-query/with clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, we can write the sql like this:
select sum(b),sum(c),sum(sum(b)+sum(c)) from t1 group by b,c;

Comment: @gsalem thanks, the analytical version works, but why?
I divided the sql into two steps, and it should work.

Comment: the analytical version works because the analytical part is computed AFTER the other parts of the query, and so works on that result (in you case, the 2 sum() you have). Read a bit on these in the Oracle SQL Ref and you'll understand how useful these can be.

Comment: @gsalem yes, `sum(b)` and `sum(c)` can not output when `sum(sum(b)+sum(c))` output, we don't know output which `sum(b)` and `sum(c)`. that's the reason why oracle give the exception.

Comment: What are you trying to do? [mcve]

Comment: Why not just use `select sum(b)+sum(c))from sub1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two levels of aggregation.

The first level of aggregation is when you "`group by a`". If you did this alone, you would get one row for each value of `A`. `sum(b)` and `sum(c)` would have specific values for each of these rows.

The second level of aggregation uses the results of the first level. When you say `sum(sum(b)+sum(c))`, you are doing a second aggregation of the results of the first aggregation. There is only one result from this second aggregation, and only one row.

Since there is only one row in the final output, where can the multiple `sum(b)` values go?

Maybe you think that `sum(b)` all by itself should be the sum of all `B` in every row of `T1`? That is not the way the syntax works. `sum(b)` says **one** aggregation, not two, so it will always be the immediate result of the `group by` operation.

What will work is `select sum(sum(b)),sum(sum(c)),sum(sum(b)+sum(c)) from t1 group by a;`. Now you are doing two levels of aggregation everywhere.

Comment: Thanks very much, More example is that, this sql:
 `select sum(b), sum(b+sum(b)) from t1 group by b;`
It works well, and I think sum(b) and sum(b+sum(b)) are in same level, right?

Comment: and I think the first `sum(b)` is not same as the second `sum(b)` in `sum(b+sum(b))`, the first `sum(b)` is computed from `b` of first level output.

Comment: First try this with only one level of aggregation: `with t1 as (select 1 b from dual)
select b, sum(b) from t1 group by b;` You are allowed to use an aggregation function on the value you group by, which gives the same result. Since it is allowed in the first level, it can be nested. If this seems strange to you, it is already strange with only one level of aggregation.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's ok to use an aggregation function on the value which group by.
But the nested aggregate result is strange in such situation. 
For example
`create table t1(a int, b int, c int); insert into t1 values(1,2,3)(10,20,30)(10,20,33);`
this sql `select sum(b), sum(b+sum(b)) from t1 group by b;` gives the result: (22, 64).

Comment: At the first level: `select b, sum(b) from b group by b;`, the output is (2, 2)(20, 40), this is ok to understand. But the second level: `select sum(b), sum(b+sum(b)) from t1 group by b;` the output is (22,64). it means that first `sum(b)` is different from `sum(b)` in `sum(b+sum(b))`, this is the most difficult to understand.